# Dashboard lights blinking wildly

Tags: electrical, subaru, electronics, forester, dashboard

[Here's a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VGPV8YSxoZo) of my Subaru Forester dashboard. Temperature, cruise, skid control, maintenance lights are on randomly and blinking. I'm guessing all of these problems are related. What could be the cause?

Comment: While not having seen the video, the most common causes for this is a low battery (one which has enough juice to start/run the engine, but the electronics freak out) and bad earth/grounds.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2. Thanks. I have a new battery, so probably the grounds? Is fixing that a DIY project?

Comment: I've seen the video. Not all lights are blinking and while the video is probably too short to judge, blinking doesn't seem to be chaotic or random. But at least CEL and ABS are steady on. I suggest you use any scan tool to try to get error codes, and I'm sure there're some. Cheap ELM327 will probably be OK.